# generator is yielded but the the yielded variable is not printed

Tags: python, generator, yield

While using generators, we yield a variable whose value is saved and will resume with that saved value when we give the `next()` statement. Is there a way where we can do this but not actually print the value of the yielded variable?

```
def foo():
    n = 0
    print("This is where we start")
    yield n
    n += 1
    print("This is first")
    yield n
    n += 1
    print("This is second")
    yield n

a = foo()
next(a)
This is where we start
0

next(a)
This is first
1
```

1. This is a very naive way of using generators(implementing them) and doesn't show their effectiveness.
2. I know that this can also be done using iterators where the value won't be printed, but just wondering if it can be done with generators.

Comment: I want the print statement to be there but the value of n not to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the *Python interactive interpreter* to call `next()`, and it is a function of that shell to print return values. What you are seeing has *nothing to do with generators*.

Simply assign the return value of the `next()` call to variable to not have them echoed:

```
ignored = next(a)
```

or run your code as a script.

Note that generators are paused *immediately*; no code inside is run until you call `next()` on it. At that point the code runs until a `yield` expression is reached; it's value is returned and the generator is paused again. At no point is the `yield` result 'saved'.